# how to read json result in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I'm not familiar with jquery. Will you please help me in this? 
I have a json respone from url but i don't know how, can i read key value in jquery.

**For example, how to get the "HAWBItemEntity" value?**

Please check the below json-response.

```
{
  "waybill_log": {
    "TrackingResult": {
      "HAWBEntity": {
        "HAWBID": 282829899,
      },
      "HAWBHistoryEntity": [
        {
          "ActionDate": "4/26/2014 12:32:00 PM",
        },
        {
          "ActionDate": "4/26/2014 12:32:00 PM",
        }
      ],
      "HAWBAttachmentEntity": [
        {
          "FileName": "Invoice_30018018516..pdf",
        }
      ],
      "HAWBItemEntity": null,
    },
    "HAWBAttachmentEntityExtendedList": [
      {
        "HAWBAttachmentEntity": {
          "FileName": "Invoice_30018018516..pdf",
        },
        "AttachmentLink": "nw"
      }
    ],
    "CurrentStatus": "Delivery",
    "ConsolsData": {
      "ConsolNumber": null,
    },
    "ItemContainerData": {
      "ContainerNumber": null,
    },
    "FlightDetails": null,
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you accept an answer if it helped you? Would be really nice for you, for other answerers, who spent time helping you and last but not least, it would make me happy too. ;-) Also, I see that you never accept an answer... that's sad

Answer (score 4):

1. Use jQuery's `jQuery.parseJSON()` method to get a JavaScript object out of your JSON-String:

   ```
   var test = jQuery.parseJSON(data); // Where 'data' is your JSON string
   ```
2. After parsing, `test` is a JavaScript object. The [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) about `parseJSON()`:

> **jQuery.parseJSON()**
>
> Takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting JavaScript
>   object.
>   ...

**About the Javascript Object:**

```
// Declaration
var Obj = {
    // Properties:
    propertyOne: 'value', // string
    propertyTwo: 52.3654, // float
    // propertyThree is an object inside 'Obj'
    // defined by the braces
    // which may naturally contain its own properties & methods
     propertyThree: { 
          propTrheeProperty: 42, // int
          propTrheeAnotherProperty: 'whatever',
          thePropThreeMethod: function () { 
            // your function code 
          }
          // and so on, no coma after the last property/method
      }, 
    // and so on
    // 'Obj' - Methods:
    methodOne: function () { 
        // your function code 
    },
    methodTwo: function () { 
        // your function code 
    }
    // and so on, no coma after the last property/method
}
```

There are two possibilities to access properties (but not methods, see below), so called *[Property Accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)*:

**- The "Dot Notation":**

*With the dot notation, you can access properties & methods*

```
var objOne = new Obj(); // Create a new instance of Obj
objOne.propertyTwo; // 52.3654

var objTwo = new Obj(); // Another instance of Obj
objTwo.propertyThtree.propTrheeProperty; // 42
objTwo.propertyThtree.propTrheeAnotherProperty; // whatever

// Accessing methods
objOne.methodOne(); // whatever your function methodOne() returns or does 
objTwo.methodTwo(); // whatever your function methodTwo() returns or does
```

**- The "Bracket Notation":**

*With the bracket notation, you can also access properties & methods*

```
objTwo['propertyThtree']['propTrheeProperty']; // 42
objOne['methodOne']();
```

instead of

```
objTwo.propertyThtree.propTrheeProperty; // 42
objOne.methodOne();
```

---

**In your case, that means:**

```
window.console.log(test.waybill_log.TrackingResult.HAWBEntity.HAWBID); 
// 282829899
```

Or

```
window.console.log(test.waybill_log.TrackingResult.HAWBEntity); 
// Should give something like: Object { HAWBID: '282829899'}
```

Or

```
window.console.log(test.waybill_log.HAWBItemEntity); 
// null
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to read json with jquery in general .

Just read it with ease , using `JSON.parse()` function and without Jquery .

```
var json = '{"result":true,"count":1}',
    obj = JSON.parse(json);

alert(obj.count);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery to get the JSON, you can just use:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

And it will parse the JSON for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = $.parseJson(jsonString);
```

To get the value 282829899 for "HAWBID", you would use:

```
var hawbid = json.waybill_log.TrackingResult.HAWBEntity.HAWBID;
```