# JavaScript json handler

Tags: javascript, json

I struggle with handling this request with simple javascript(if possible no jQuery).
Screenshot of the input info: http://prntscr.com/3kx7sx
The goal is that I need to break those lines into var's:

```
["buy","1400595135855","8511315","0.007379"]
```

Can someone please give me a hand?

Comment: What have *you* tried so far?

Comment: I searched on stackoverflow and google something close, but this "[[" cofuses me alot...

Comment: It is just an Object with an Array in an Array.

Comment: What do you mean with "break those lines into var's"?

Comment: @Johan He meant to transform all single values in single variables

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310353/how-to-read-json-result-in-jquery/23310376#23310376

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). You'll need to pass in the JSON string that you showed in the image. So like this:

```
// You'll need to figure out a way to fill in the '...' with your JSON string,
// probably with an AJAX call.
var jsonString = '...'

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);

for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.data.length; i++) {
    // Here, we're iterating through the data array on the returned object.
    var dataItem = jsonObj.data[i];

    // You can now access properties of each data item using dataItem[<index>]
    // and do whatever you need to with them.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should simply iterate through the array like this:

```
var a = ["buy","1400595135855","8511315","0.007379"];

for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    console.log(a[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since nested arrays seems to confuse you, here is a snippet to convert the response an array of objects.

```
var response = {  
    e: 'history-update',
    data: [["buy","1400595135855","8511315","0.007379"],
           ["buy","1400595135855","8511315","0.007379"]]
};

var result = response.data.map(function(item){
    var ret = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < item.length; i++)
        ret['item_' + i] = item[i];
    return ret;
});

console.log(result[0].item_0); // 'buy'
```

I just called the properties `item_<index>`. Does this help you?

http://jsfiddle.net/nTPX3/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the values in individual variables, without the restriction of only using them in a loop or one by one, this is the way to go. If your number of parameters in the Json response is not always the same, then a loop is better.

```
 var a = ["buy","1400595135855","8511315","0.007379"];
    var value1 = a[0];
    var value2 = a[1];
    var value3 = a[2];
    var value4 = a[3];
```