# How to set json data as a variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got thte follwoing json data with me

```
 {
                            "id": "0004",
                            "name": "Thums Up",
                            "image":{"url": "images/0001.jpg","width": 200,"height": 200},
                            "Can":[ "250ml", "300ml","330ml", {"image":"images/0001.jpg" }],
                            "Bottle":[ "350ml",  "600ml", {"image":"images/0001.jpg" } ],
                            "Fountain":["small", "large", {"image":"images/0001.jpg" }]
                        }
```

I want to use the above json data inside my html file so i am manually removing all the spaces and assigning it this way

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

    var jsondata = ' {"id": "0004","name": "Thums Up","image":{"url": "images/0001.jpg","width": 200,"height": 200},
    "Can":[ "250ml", "300ml","330ml", {"image":"images/0001.jpg" }],"Bottle":[ "350ml",  "600ml", {"image":"images/0001.jpg" } ],"Fountain":["small", "large", {"image":"images/0001.jpg" }]}';
    });
    </script>
```

If the json data is big then its really taking so much of time doing this .
Is there any way or tool  i can do this automatically ??

Comment: if you're hard-coding it, why keep it as _JSON_ and not switch to an _Object literal_?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310353/how-to-read-json-result-in-jquery/23310376#23310376

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want json data as string format then you have to use JSON.stringify function.

See below example :

```
var jsonData = {
        "id": "0004",
        "name": "Thums Up",
        "image": { "url": "images/0001.jpg", "width": 200, "height": 200 },
        "Can": ["250ml", "300ml", "330ml", { "image": "images/0001.jpg" }],
        "Bottle": ["350ml", "600ml", { "image": "images/0001.jpg" }],
        "Fountain": ["small", "large", { "image": "images/0001.jpg" }]
    };
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a subset of javascript. Which means that JSON can be *directly parsed* as javascript. So leave off those outer quotes and it should work fine.

```
var jsondata = {
    "id": "0004",
    "name": "Thums Up",
    "image": {
        "url": "images/0001.jpg",
        "width": 200,
        "height": 200
    },
    "Can": ["250ml", "300ml", "330ml", {
        "image": "images/0001.jpg"
    }],
    "Bottle": ["350ml", "600ml", {
        "image": "images/0001.jpg"
    }],
    "Fountain": ["small", "large", {
        "image": "images/0001.jpg"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Except this isn't _JSON_ anymore because it's not a _String_

Comment: Which might be better, depending on what it's being used for. But technically you are correct.

Comment: @Alex Wayne , so you mean to say that i don't need to give outer quotes and it will be done automatically know ??.

Comment: If you have that json as a string , use `JSON.parse()` to convert it to an object.

Answer (score 0):

Run in any js console: (or you can put it as is in your code)

```
JSON.stringify({
                            "id": "0004",
                            "name": "Thums Up",
                            "image":{"url": "images/0001.jpg","width": 200,"height": 200},
                            "Can":[ "250ml", "300ml","330ml", {"image":"images/0001.jpg" }],
                            "Bottle":[ "350ml",  "600ml", {"image":"images/0001.jpg" } ],
                            "Fountain":["small", "large", {"image":"images/0001.jpg" }]
                        })
```