# how iterate through this json object (not with jquery)

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to iterate through a json object which I got from `var jsonObj json_encode( <?php echo $php_array ?>);`. This looks to me like a different format to what most people have. For example, w3schools shows this as a json object:

```
{
    "employees": [
        { "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
        { "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
        { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
    ]
}
```

Mine seems to have completely structure:

```
{"PINEFOREST JEWELRY":
    ["3034.25","2002-01-02"],
"AMBERS DESIGN":
    ["2034.75","2002-01-02"],
"ELEGANT JEWELERS":
    ["206","2002-01-02"],
"SALEM'S JEWELERS":
    ["406","2002-01-02"]}
```

Am I able to iterate through this?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310353/how-to-read-json-result-in-jquery/23310376#23310376

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for in` with a nested `for`

```
for (var key in data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data[key].length; i++) {
        console.log(data[key][i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This gets me the numbers, how do I also get the names?

Comment: The name is stored in the `key` variable @bsapaka

Comment: `Document.write(sales_new_accounts[key][i]` gives me just numbers, and `Document.write(sales_new_accounts[key]` gives me undefined

Comment: @bsapaka -- You have to use that within the loop - `key` outside the loop is nothing

Comment: yes, I did use that inside the for loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to iterate through the object's direct properties as follows:

```
var val;
for(var key in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        val = obj[key];
        console.log(val);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since it's JSON there's no real need to use `hasOwnProperty` in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can itterate through it as it is valid json.

To start of you need to convert the json into something javascript can itterate over, which you can do with `JSON.parse()` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)). Im assuming that the 'json' you described above is a string of 'json' so:

```
var jewellery = JSON.parse(myJson); // replace myJson with whatever variable is holding your json
```

At this point you have an `object` which you can itterate over. One of the easiest ways to do this would be by using `Object.keys()` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)) and `Array.forEach()` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)) like so:

```
Object.keys(jewellery).forEach(function (key) {
    console.log(key); // would log 'PINEFOREST JEWELRY' the first time
    jewellery[key].forEach(function (price) {
        console.log(price); // Should log '3034.25' the first time
    }
});
```

Give that a try, otherwise you could still use the other solutions other people have submitted, either or would work. This is how I would do it though!!

Comment: Be careful with the forEach function as it isn't supported in some browsers like IE8 (http://caniuse.com/#search=forEach)

Comment: That can be a concern yes, which is why I said give it a try and if it doesn't work then use the other solutions people have submitted :)