# How to convert large JSON string into array with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a JSON string that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "acbPreviewCell",
        "width": 80
    },
    {
        "id": "advName",
        "width": 170
    },
    {
        "id": "adHeadline",
        "width": 150
    },
    {
        "id": "adSize",
        "width": 150
    },
    {
        "id": "adProduct",
        "width": 150
    },
    {
        "id": "adCategory",
        "width": 150
    },
    {
        "id": "adSection",
        "width": 150
    },
    {
        "id": "adColor",
        "width": 150
    },
    {
        "id": "adTags",
        "width": 150
    },
    {
        "id": "adRegions",
        "width": 150
    },
    {
        "id": "adStatus",
        "width": 150
    },
    {
        "id": "adCreated",
        "width": 150
    },
    {
        "id": "adBookingNb",
        "width": 150
    },
    {
        "id": "adPickup",
        "width": 150
    },
    {
        "id": "folioMeta",
        "width": 150
    }
]
```

To help explain further, each of these entries is the ID of a table header, along with the width of that table header. I'm using it within an application so that I can remember a user's custom column width that they set.

I would like to break this JSON string down into a javascript array, so that I can easily access each ID and it's width.

Any help would be appreciated with setting it up as an array and then breaking it down to access the ID and the width. Thank you!

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310353/how-to-read-json-result-in-jquery/23310376#23310376

Comment: Where is the string stored? It syntactically already *is* a JavaScript array.

Comment: `var myarray = JSON.parse(myjsonString)`

Comment: Sounds like maybe a hash keyed on the `id` values would be more useful.

Comment: Are you asking [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)? or how to [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/710446)?

Comment: Thank you for the references guys it really helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to convert it to an [*array*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) you can use the [built-in JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) to parse it: `JSON.parse(yourString)`.

But if you want to easily access values by ID, you will have to actually convert it to an [*object*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object):

```
var originalData = JSON.parse(yourString);
var parsedData = {};
for (var i = 0, l = originalData.length; i < l; i++) {
    parsedData[originalData[i].id] = originalData[i].width;
}

// now you can easily access the wanted widths
var acbPreviewCellWidth = parsedData['acbPreviewCellWidth'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone else mentioned a hashed map, which is pretty much what I'm guessing you need. That is to say, you want to access by id quickly as in `array['advName']` gives you the width there.

You could mill through the values you get like so:

```
a = [
    {
        "id": "acbPreviewCell",
        "width": 80
    },
    {
        "id": "advName",
        "width": 170
    },
    {
        "id": "adHeadline",
        "width": 150
    }
];

function rewrite_array(arr){
    new_arr = new Array();
    for( i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        new_arr[arr[i]['id']] = arr[i]['width'];
    }
    return new_arr;
}

n = rewrite_array(a);
console.log(n["advName"]);
console.log(a[1]['width']);
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory, it already is stored as an array. However, if you would like to parse the JSON object to ensure that it is properly formed, use `var jsonArray = JSON.parse(jsonString);` No jQuery is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery.parseJSON(jsonString)](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to get the JSON using ajax, and then loop through all the values lushing them to an array in javascript, or you can simply call `var objArr = $.parseJSON('file');` to get an array of all the objects. If you want to fet the values, you van simply get them using `objArr[index].val`.

Using this you can call, for instance, the first objects values like this.

```
var id = objArr[0].id;
var width = objArr[0].width;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function filtered(v) {
  return $.map(json, function(value) {
    return value.id === v ? value : null
  })[0];
};
```

usage

```
filtered("folioMeta"); // do stuff with "folioMeta" object within array
filtered("folioMeta").id // `"folioMeta"`
filtered("folioMeta").width // `150`
```