# how to iterate this kind of json?

Tags: jquery

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John",
        "age": 11
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Maria",
        "age": 12
    },
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "store": "market place",
            "phone": 1234567890,
            "type": "market"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "store": "ration",
            "phone": 1234567890,
            "type": "animal"
        }
    ]
]
```

I'm trying to get the `store`, `phone`, and `type` values. But I only got the `name` and `age`.

I have this:

```
$.each(data, function (i, x) {
     alert(x.phone) // give all null 4x times
});
```

How can I iterate all my json? I tried to add another `each` but its showing me `undefined`

Comment: try `$.each(data[2], function(i, x) {` ...

Comment: See this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310353/how-to-read-json-result-in-jquery/23310376#23310376 maybe it helps to know about JS-objects

Comment: try $.each(data[0][2], function(i, x){.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats is very wierd datastructure. Problem si that you have two types there, objects and at the end of array, another array.
So to get store and phone values you need to identify the array in this array:

```
$.each(data, function(i, x) {
    //Test if item is array
    if ($.isArray(x)) {
        //If it is, cycle throught it, find desired data
        $.each(x, function(i2, x2) {
            alert(x2.phone)
            alert(x2.store)
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I know it's weird and wrong for me, but it was necessary until I think another way of what I'm trying to do.