# javascript json ajax data parsing

Tags: jquery, html, css, json, ajax

I am new to ajax and jquery programming. I am designing weather web app which display the weather for certain city on the website. I have been able to successful display weather on to website. But now I want to take the temperature from JSON and convert it into Fahrenheit. Here is my code for the web app

```
        $(function(){


     $('#clickme').click(function() {
         $("#weather").empty();

        var search_City2 = $("#c1").val();

        $.ajax({
          url: 'http://localhost:3000/?id='+search_City2,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) {
             var items = [];

             $.each(data, function(key, val) {

               items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + key + ' : '+ val + '</li>');

             });

             $('<ul/>', {
                'class': 'weather-list',
                html: items.join('')
             }).appendTo('#weather');
             var city = search_City2;


          },
         statusCode: {
            404: function() {
              alert('There was a problem with the server.  Try again soon!');
            }
          }
       });
     });
 });
```

Here is my JSON Data

```
{ text: 'Light Rain',
  temp: '12',
  date: 'Fri, 27 Nov 2015 11:00 am EST',
  high: '14',
  low: '-2' }
```

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310353/how-to-read-json-result-in-jquery/23310376#23310376

Comment: What does `console.dir(jQuery.parseJSON(data));` produce in your success function?

Comment: in console log it is "null"

Comment: So nothing comes back from call to server...? `console.dir(data)`  OR is it just the JSON with the single quotes (which are invalid JSON )

Comment: this is the reply "object    date: "Fri, 27 Nov 2015 12:59 pm EST"
high: "13"
low: "-1"
temp: "12"
text: "Light Rain"  " when i used "console.dir(data)"

Comment: you should get `{"text":"Light Rain","temp":"12","date":"Fri, 27 Nov 2015 11:00 am EST","high":"14","low":"-2"}` for a valid JSON string

Comment: is there any other way to extract temperature from the data i am receiving

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
var jsObj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); // Convert string JSON to object

if (jsObj.temp) {

    var temp = parseFloat(jsObj.temp.toString());
    var tempFahrenheit = temp * 33.8; // 1 Celcuis = 33.8 Fahrenheit

    console.log('Temperature: ' + tempFahrenheit + 'ºF');
}
```

Comment: getting error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp' of null"

Comment: if condition change to "if (jsObj && jsObj.temp)"

Comment: it does run my script but does not log anything into console this is what i get when i debug it "jsObj = null, temp = undefine"

Answer (score 0):

this is working code ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          var data = { text: 'Light Rain',
                       temp: '12',
                       date: 'Fri, 27 Nov 2015 11:00 am EST',
                       high: '14',
                       low: '-2' };

          $.each(data, function (k, v) {
              if(k == 'temp'){
                  var cToFahr = v * 9 / 5 + 32;
                  console.log(v, cToFahr);
              }
          });
     });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```